# If matrix $P$ is positive semidefinite, is $C^TPC$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Or if it's a conditionally true statement, what must be true about the matrix $C$ to make $C^TPC$ PSD?

edit - all matrices are made of real numbers.

edit - here is the issue I'm running into that is made me want to confirm this (MATLAB programming):

> eigs(H)

ans =

```
0.1128
0.0001
0.0001
0.0001
```

$P = C^THC$

% Where H is symmetric, 4x4, and the multiplying matrix is size 4x330, mostly zeros

> chol(P)
>   Error using chol
>   Matrix must be positive definite.

So it seems multiplication did not preserve being positive definite.

Comment: What's the context for this?

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant. This is a general question I have. I am doing a change of variables on a quadratic form; the previous matrix was PSD, but now the result is not (to numerical precision).

Comment: It's helpful so people can tell you are not just copying problems from an assignment.  I'm not saying you were, but it happens a lot on here.

Comment: It is true for all matrices $C$ and PSD $P$, as Cameron's statement shows.

Comment: Right. Not a homework problem by any means. I ran into a weird numerical issue in MATLAB so I started thinking in general about what I was doing, and came up with this question to confirm.

Comment: @Qudit There is not problem with copying problems from an assignment.

Comment: @ABC I was commenting on the _original_ version of this post; there was no way to tell before it was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that you used transpose and not adjoint, I'll assume that you are working with real matrices over $\Bbb R^n$. (If you want this to work for complex inner product spaces, you'll need to use the adjoint in place of transpose in general.) Let's consider what happens with $C^TPC$ in an inner product:

$$\langle C^TPC x,x\rangle = \langle PCx,(C^T)^T x\rangle = \langle PCx,Cx\rangle.$$

Do you see where to go from here?

Comment: Yes all real numbers; no, I don't see where to go from here though =(

Comment: @JDS what is your definition of PSD?

Comment: @JDS Try a "change of variable." You want to use the fact that $P$ is positive-semidefinite which means that **for any** vector $y$, $\langle Py,y\rangle \ge 0$. Do you see a $y$ lurking in the expression above?

Comment: Oh yes, $ y = Cx $, so I guess it must be PSD? BTW I define this as all eigenvalues being nonnegative. I think I may just have numerical conditioning issues because I get some very small negative eigenvalues. Do you think it would be appropriate to add a small $\epsilon \ge 0$ to the diagonal entries to fix this?

Comment: @JDS ah.  The usual definition is that $P$ is PSD iff $P$ is symmetric and
$$
x^TPx \geq 0 \quad \forall x \in \Bbb R^n
$$
this is equivalent to the statement that $P$ is symmetric with positive eigenvalues.

Comment: @JDS if you're getting negative eigenvalues, it must be because you have some issues with numerical precision. My guess would be that $P$ has a zero eigenvalue but the corresponding eigenvalue of $C^TPC$ is turning negative because of round off errors. So yes, you probably want to *slightly* boost the zero eigenvalue of $P$ (by some very small positive number) to compensate. These sorts of issues plague numerical linear algebra. Linear algebra is a spectacular theory but in practice, things do not work out nearly as nicely as intended because of the innacuracy of machine precision.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom you are correct I forgot the fact that the matrix $P$ is symmetric (as is $C^TPC$).

Comment: @CameronWilliams I updated my question showing the exact issue. I clearly start with a positive definite matrix (as confirmed by the eigenvalues). But after multiplication this is no longer the case.

Comment: @JDS Positive-semidefinite and positive definite are *very* different animals. Positive-semidefiniteness is preserved by conjugating by a matrix. Positivity is most definitely not because you need the resulting matrix to be invertible (no zero eigenvalues). If $C$ were square (which it isn't), you would need that $C$ is invertible in order for $C^TPC$ to be positive-definite. When your dimensions do not match, there isn't any hope of retaining positivity, I think, because one of $C$ and $C^T$ will necessarily have a nontrivial kernel. To see this, apply the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Write $P= P^{1/2} P^{1/2}$ where $P^{1/2}$ is a symmetric square root of $P$. Since $P$ is positive definite, it has such a symmetric square root (take its eigen-decomposition and replace the eigenvalues with their square roots, for example).

Clearly, $C^T P C$ is symmetric.

Then, $x^T C^T P C x= x^T C^T P^{1/2} P^{1/2} C x = (P^{1/2} C x)^T (P^{1/2} C x) = ||P^{1/2} C x||^2 \geq 0$.

So, $C^T P C$ is positive semi-definite as well.

Note that theres a difference between positive definite and positive semi-definite (the latter allowing zero eigenvalues, which chol in matlab does not like).

Comment: Oh, so $C^TPC$ need not be strictly positive definite... Damn, that's a pain. I don't suppose there's a symmetric square root decomposition for a positive semi-definite matrix in general?

Comment: Answering my own question, it seems like the LDL decomposition, for symmetric indefinite matrices, is what I'm looking for: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ldl.html

Comment: I showed you one. Take an eigendecomposition of the matrix and replace its eigenvalues with the square roots of the eigenvalues. The resultant matrix is symmetric and squares to be the original matrix.